# How to create a dropdown of foreign keys in a template?

Tags: django, django-templates

Without crispy forms I can create a form as follows

```
<form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}

        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="{{ project.name }}"/>

            </div>
```

However I do not know how to create a dropdown **of foreign keys**.

I cannot use cripsy forms because I want to seperate the fields by headings and I am not using a forms.py file so I don't believe the layouts feature will work.

What is the correct methodology?

The files are setup as below

models.py

```
  class ProjectsTypes(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
    
        class Meta:
            ordering = ('name', )


    class Projects(models.Model):
        fk_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        d_started = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, 
        fk_type = models.ForeignKey(ProjectTypes, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
        notes_design = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
        notes_process = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
    
        class Meta:
            ordering = ('name', )
```

views.py

class Projects(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):

```
model = Projects
fields = ['name', 'fk_type', 'notes_design', 'notes_process']
template_name = 'projects/details_project.html'
context_object_name = 'projects'

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.fk_user = self.request.user
    form.save()
    # return super().form_valid(form)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.path_info)

def test_func(self):
    post = self.get_object()
    if self.request.user == post.fk_user:
        return True
    return False
```

Comment: Can you provide the models you are working with? That way I can better understand your use case and provide an example. What do you exactly by separating the fields by heading?

However, it seems you may need a queryset from the related data in your views, add that data to your context and loop over.

Comment: @theeomm - i've updated the question with context, I would happily use cripsy forms however I'd like to have a <h2> heading of 'Notes' seperating the notes fields from the other in the template.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the `form` inside the template you could use the queryset it's already got

#### template.html

```py
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="{{ project.name }}"/>

    <select id="id_fk_type" name="fk_type">
        {% for i in form.fk_type.field.queryset.all %}
            <option value="{{i.pk}}">{{i}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</div>
```

If you do not have access to the form you've got to manually pass a Queryset to the template and loop through that.
But in both example's the `<option>` values are the PrimaryKey

---

#### Edit

Try changing your form_valid function to manually set the field

```py
    def form_valid(self, form):
        print(self.request.POST)
        form.instance.fk_user = self.request.user
        form.instance.fk_type = ProjectsTypes.objects.filter(pk=self.request.POST.get('fk_type')).first()
        form.save()
        # return super().form_valid(form)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.path_info)
```

Comment: With your help the list is now appearing however will not save the choice, perhaps an ID issue?

Comment: It should be added that I am not using a forms.py file, I am creating the template from views

Comment: Okay, I made an edit; Try that. ...and if you're not using a forms.py, then what form is `form_valid` using and how is `form.fk_type.field.queryset.all` available in the template- very, very odd

Comment: I'm unsure as I have never used forms before, only views and templates - I was able to update the name field without a forms.py file simply in the template as in the example I posted - should I create a forms.py file? I'm just unsure how to link this to my url and template.

Comment: naw, you should be find without a forms.py, clearly Django is handling it somehow it's probably just using the default Admin form.. But it might be something to look into. How'd the edit work?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't change anything, I may also be adding additional foreign key fields down the line so perhaps there's a more common way to set this up?

Comment: ...well that not correct... could you show me what the output of the `print(self.request.POST)` says?- maybe the value isn't getting posted or something

Comment: <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['RODjkIVRO9UAPgqd8TxA3bVvAW72K8ApuLDMYvIybtF5RgVOkk8uxsONOfbc25kl'], 'fk_type': ['2']}>

Comment: POST /test/1 HTTP/1.1" 302 0

Comment: "GET /test/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 2728